# TinyMCE: How can I detect this event?

Tags: events, tinymce

I'm working on a plugin which incorporates an image gallery with TinyMCE.
Roughly it works like whenever I press on of the images (which are situated in a div just below my editor) the id of the clicked image will get picked up with ajax and sent to a function that injects this code into TinyMCE:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgsrc[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $imgsrc[1]; ?>">
```

It all works like it should, however I want to be able to track when this happens in the editor. I use onEvent like so:

```
ed.onEvent.add(function(ed, e) {
         console.debug('Editor event occured: ' + e.target.nodeName);
});
```

It won't pick up any event at all, is there someway to make TinyMCE aware of what just happened?

[DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/mvcaab)

Thanks.

Comment: @Thariama How do you mean? The img src injection is called when the image is clicked. The onEvent handler notices everything that happens in the editor besides my injection. I.E. if I move the cursor och select anything it'll pop up in the console, but not the img injection.

Comment: can you provide an online example (tinymce fiddle) ior provide some more code?

Comment: @Thariama Ok, here it is: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/mvcaab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get any output because you use `setContent` on the selection - not on the editor instance. And this is a big difference because there is no listener listening for this to fire.

Comment: Is there a way for me to add a listener so I can know when content (in this case an image) is inserted? setContent on the selection is important because I want the image to be inserted where the cursor is.

Comment: you know when it gets inserted (it is here : tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(data);). isn't it suffcient to call desired code right after this line of code?